# How do I ignore the end of a url parameter string in Htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a bunch of ugly links coming in to a site like this:

```
https://www.somedomain.com/mm5/mch.mvc?Session_ID=5f59c6e0&Screen=PRODFB&Product_Code=pcode1&Category_Code=category_a&Store_Code=store1&fb=1
```

I'm trying to use htaccess to recreate the url like this:

```
https://www.somedomain.com/mm5/mch.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=pcode1
```

I've come up with this but of course it isn't working. I think I just need to be able to ignore the rest of the url parameter after the product_code param but not sure how to do it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^Screen=PRODFB&Product_Code=([^/.]+)$ /mm5/mch.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule` directive.

As long as query parameters are same as what you have in question, you may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(mm5/mch\.mvc)\?.*&Screen=PRODFB&(Product_Code=[^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?Screen=PROD&%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Or using `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)Screen=PRODFB&(Product_Code=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^mm5/mch\.mvc/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?Screen=PROD&%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to change the param Screen=PRODFB to Screen=PROD, can I tweak your example above to make that happen?

Comment: That didn't work for me, I think there was an issue with %{THE_REQUEST}, but I did get it to work using the answer I posted below. Thanks for your help, it gave me some ideas to get this working.

Comment: Your rule is matching `.*` in `RewriteRule` which means it will also redirect `/abc/123/?Session_ID=5f59c6e0&Screen=PRODFB&Product_Code=pcode1&Category_Code=category_a&Store_Code=store1&fb=1` not just  `/mm5/mch\.mvc` URI. See my updated answer for correct use.

Comment: Ah, good point. Your code works great, thank you for your help. I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it work like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Screen=PRODFB&Product_Code=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mm5/mch.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=%1& [R=301,L,NE]
```